# Adding polarity protection to this circuit

Tags: power-supply, power

[image]

Anyone know the best way to add polarity protection to this circuit?

[image]

Comment: No.  Do you want to correct, block or short the wrong polarity supply?

Comment: I see there is a current sink in the circuit, what is the amount of current that the current sink will pull??? This can affect which approach to take for adding polarity protection

Comment: The switch matrix = 1mΩ so to avoid conduction losses makes diode blocking not feasible. >20A is excessive for LiPo. Is this for vaping? Is it OK to fuse with reverse diode shunt.

Comment: @skvery. I need the circuit not to work with the battery inserted the wrong way.

Comment: Do you want to correct, short or block the connection?

Comment: @brhans. Im not fluent in the dynamics of this stack exchange yet. Please excuse me while I get up to speed.

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. Weirdly it did start at vaping, but then it grew legs so I ran with it haha. My lihv lipo is capible of 120c 31wh, 20a is easily attained.

Comment: @Tony Stewart.  Fuse with reverse diode shunt.. depends if the fuse is resettable and doesn't impact to limit output

Comment: What is the purpose of the device, and what battery is used with it?

Comment: @bruce Abbott.  Handheld heating element device.  I'll update the original question with a pic of the battery and spec. I will also use its 2s 7.8v cousin, though I do not have it to hand.

Comment: @skvery. I've no idea haha. That's why I'm here ;) I don't like the sound of short if that helps, let's go with block..

Comment: Would a diode work? There are also mosfet solutions that prevent reverse polarity. They even make IC's for this purpose.

Comment: I am shocked to see that RC racing car batteries are still being provided with non-polarized banana sockets!

Comment: Not kidding Bruce! I doubt I'll make the mistake tbh, hope not, because it's the kind of thing you only get chance to do once!

Comment: A forward diode will block battery reversal.  A bridge rectifier will correct it.  Use Schottky diodes to reduce the forward voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit may not need 'protection' as such. If polarity is reversed the FETs will simply conduct through their body diodes, causing the heater to turn on continuously. The FETs will get hotter than normal, but hopefully the user will quickly disconnect the battery after noticing that the heater has immediately turned on and the switch has no effect.

To make it more 'idiot-proof' you could install a loud buzzer across the supply input, with a diode in series so it only sounds if the battery polarity is wrong. When the user tries to plug a battery in the wrong way around the buzzer will go off.

I would also use a *polarized* battery connector. If someone wishes to use a battery with non-polarized connections then they will have to make an adapter cable to match your connector, and they will be responsible for making sure the polarity is correct.

Comment: Polarized connector seems to be the simplest solution and effective solution

Comment: I'd thought to put a 5mm banana socket on the live side, but those dam lipos scare me, taking a soldering iron to one would be a last resort! I've got precious little room in the enclosure but i'll look into the buzzer idea, thanks!

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pui-audio-inc/AI-1027-TWT-5V-2-R/668-1454-ND/5011389

Answer (score 0):

[Reverse Schottky Diode](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/4c/4c/63/5a/77/8a/44/2b/CD00001327.pdf/files/CD00001327.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001327.pdf) rated for max current with suitable heatsink, as reverse leakage rises dramatically with Tjcn from 6 to 500mA at 100'C

STPS20L15 
Dual diode 0.41V max at 19A each  2.5W at 10A  $0.87 (1k)

Comment: Not sure if I'm supposed to answer here, seeing this screen on mobile device is confusing.. there's two reply boxes :s as your answer came up in this one I'll answer it here :) I'd already planned an Nmos circuit with Scottky diode to counter avelanche, adding it to this one works for me. Just need to know exactly where on the circuit to add your suggestion Tony.

Comment: @mike_1 In series with the battery!